# How many units of each iOS version are currently in usage?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Anyone know where I can find stats on how many units are currently running each major version of iOS (1-4). I'm trying to decide if it's prudent to use functionality only available in iOS 4. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for the same iOS usage information. There's definitely a lack of current information on it. Everything I've read points to that iOS4 usage is lower than what most people expect. Apparently Google Analytics doesn't have the ability to break down iPhone traffic by iOS version even though it's right there in the userAgent string.

Comment: What is it with closing these highly relevant questions?  A programmer needs to know how many users use what version.  This helps support decisions about what to support and where to focus one's efforts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found this article on the web : https://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2010/08/recent-ios-version-statistics-from-delhi-city-metro

Updated : [March 2011](https://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2011/03/is-it-worth-supporting-ios-3-in-2011)

Comment: Thanks for this. Best info I've seen to date. Ideally though, I'd like to see numbers for more than just one app. Also, although I didn't mention it, I'm really just interested in US figures (Authors says 80% of users for this app are from India).

Comment: http://www.journaldugeek.com/2010/07/27/50-diphones-sous-ios-4/ another link with US stats

Comment: Thanks for that. Great sample size with that data (9 million devices). However, it looks like that survey was conducted sometime in July of this year, only a month after the release of ios. 4 months later, I would think that greater than 50% of ios devices use ios4. Anyhow, thanks for your help with this. I've accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my blog MathieuF, I have just posted a more in depth analysis of iOS versions based on my own experience. http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2011/03/is-it-worth-supporting-ios-3-in-2011.html

Comment: I've updated my answer with your new stats.

Comment: Some newer stats: http://pxldot.com/post/18754186750/ios-ebb-and-flow (not entirely convinced this question should be closed, every answer is factual)

Answer (score 8):

The same company that provided the data for the accepted answer (Chitika, Inc.) has published data for January 2011: [61% of iPads Already Running iOS 4 – January iOS and Android OS Breakdown](http://chitika.com/research/2011/61-of-ipads-already-running-ios-4-january-ios-and-android-os-breakdown/) iOS 3.x for iPhone's share appears to have decreased by 33%!

Comment: A recent Chikita blog shows that iOS 2.x/3.x usage has dropped to around 6% of all devices: http://insights.chitika.com/2011/just-in-time-for-ios-5-ios-3-almost-dead/

Answer (score 8):

Marco Arment tells [here](http://www.marco.org/2011/08/13/instapaper-ios-device-and-version-stats-update) that his application instapaper had these stats (13 aug 2011)

iOS 4.x: 98.4%

iOS 3.x: 1.6%

(iPad, iPhone and Ipod)

David Lieb (Bump CEO) tells [here](http://www.quora.com/What-proportion-of-all-iPhone-owners-use-iOS4-%2a-today) that the application Bump had these stats for iOS between January 7 and January 10, 2011.

iOS 4.X: 89.73 %

iOS 3.X: 10.25 %

iOS 2.X: 0.02 %

(Note that this includes both iPhones and iPads)

Answer (score 0):

Most users can easily upgrade to iOS 4 for free, so your app requiring iOS 4 might actually be an incentive for users to upgrade.  Only the original iPhone is still stuck as iOS 3.1.3.

Comment: Or the reluctance to upgrade (and keep decent battery life) is an incentive for not installing unnecessary apps :-)