# Is it worth supporting an older iOS for a new iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, ios, compatibility

I just released our new iPhone game.

This is my first app, and right now it's only supported for iOS 4.2, mostly since the device I tested on is upgraded. The game works well on it.

My question is, to make it compatible with older versions (pre 4.0) is going to mean modifying code and replacing iAds. Is it worth it? Are the pre-4.0 numbers large enough to patch the current game?

Answer (score 2):

**Addition:** I have a feeling this might be moved to Programmers Stack Exchange since it is subjective and doesn't have to do with a specific coding issue.

This is completely subjective on my part and therefor worthless.

Apple really.. really....... (Can I stress this enough) does not like their customers to be on older versions of their software. I don't even think you can develop for iOS 4.2 without Snow Leopard Patch x.x.

You seem worried about pre-4.0. I will assume then that 4.0 and 4.1 users can run your game. Personally I would focus on fixing bugs, more levels, newer version, another game, etc. then making it work on pre-4.0.

By the time you make it work on pre-4.0, 4.3 will be out. The backwards compatible route, while noble, can sometimes destroy a company.

Comment: Same opinion here. Plus, the reason why some of the users are still using iOS 3.x is simply that their iDevices are jailbreak. Trust me you don't never ever want to debug and development with a jailbreak iPhone...

Comment: Apple should have figures with percentage of users on different devices like Android does!

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242606/how-many-units-of-each-ios-version-are-currently-in-usage) for some data that may help you decide.

Comment: Thanks guys! That makes a lot of sense.