# iOS Version statistics

Tags: ios, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many units of each iOS version are currently in usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242606/how-many-units-of-each-ios-version-are-currently-in-usage)

I'm trying to see which versions of iOS I should support. I'm looking for some up to date statistics about worldwide usage of each version (not just 3 and 4, but 3.1, 3.4, etc ...).

Is there a reliable source for this kind of information?

Comment: and you had a similar previous question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242606/how-many-units-of-each-ios-version-are-currently-in-usage

Comment: No, it is not the same question. It says "are currently running each major version of iOS (1-4). " Which is why I specified in my question "not just 3 and 4, but 3.1, 3.4, etc"

Answer (score 1):

if you use a search engine (I used "iOS version statistics" as search terms), there are no official number but many say that more of 90% of their users have iOS4.

do you already have an app ? if yes, you could use a statictis API ( google analytics for example) and see what is the iOS distribution for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Last January it was widely stated by big developers that about 90% had already upgraded to iOS4.  A long time has gone by since then, and through anecdotal discussion with other developers I am left with an impression that only a couple percent of users who would bother installing anything still have iOS 3.  I haven't seen a pre 3gs iPhone on the streets since last year.

I suggest that most developers should *target iOS 4+ if they can make good use of its new features.*